# Is it true that "One-Eyed Willy" means "penis"?

Tags: language, linguistics

I’d like to verify a claim found on several platforms, with regards to [sexual innuendo in the movie "The Goonies"](https://generalsnobbery.com/filmanalysis/thegoonies).

The website states the following:

> The boys are looking for the treasure of One-Eyed Willie. **“One-Eyed
> Willie” is a name for a penis.** The fact they are looking for his
> treasure indicates they seek a positive relationship with their penis,
> which has been conditioned to be surrounded in shame and confusion.

This claim seems to be supported by other unofficial sources, like [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=one-eyed%20willy) (where anyone can add a random definition of a word), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/mze1xi/oneeyed_willy_is_a_euphemism_for_penis_shout_out/?rdt=58691) (another random claim) and [many others](https://suda51.fandom.com/wiki/One-Eyed_William). This is a [list published on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-slang-terms-euphemisms-for-a-penis/answer/Garrick-Saito) and here there is [an extensive research on the term "willy"](https://www.laetusinpraesens.org/musings/willy.php) but only a single mention of "one-eyed willy", which does not cite any source whatsoever.

I'm not a native speaker, so I can only check the usage of this expression based on the English corpus. This is the result from Ngram:

[image]

Using english-corpora.org resulted in barely 50+ mentions of "one-eyed willy" and none seems to be used as a reference for penis.

[image]

Is this a made up definition or is there any truth to the sexual innuendo?

Comment: There's [one-eyed trouser snake](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/one-eyed-trouser-snake) dating back to [1970s](https://www.wordsense.eu/one-eyed_trouser_snakes/), and "willy" as a slang term seems to date to [1900s](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/willy) at the latest. Even if "one-eyed willy" weren't a coined phrase as such, it would still probably elicit some giggles.

Comment: As a native English English-speaker I'd have immediately understood this as a double-entendre there only as a joke, but without any deeper meaning. Not putting this as an answer because its OR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The earliest references I see for the exact term "One Eyed Willy" meaning penis are from 1996:

According to [Do We Really Know what Love Is?
A Guide for Improving Love Relationships](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Do_We_Really_Know_what_Love_Is/AfruddseFJYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22One-Eyed%20Willy%22%20penis&dq=%22One-Eyed%20Willy%22%20penis&printsec=frontcover) (1996):

> Here below are some words males and females use for their vagina and penis...One-Eyed-Willy

See also [Just Before Midnight](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Just_Before_Midnight/DWrj_5be9UAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=Men%27s%20brains%20%22One-%20Eyed%20Willy%20does%20all%20the%20thinking%22&dq=Men%27s%20brains%20%22One-%20Eyed%20Willy%20does%20all%20the%20thinking%22&printsec=frontcover) (1996)

> Men's brains are in their pants! And One-Eyed Willy does all the thinking

However, prior to the movie, multiple expressions beginning with "one-eyed" were known to mean "penis":

"one eyed trouser snake" [Folklore in Situ](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Folklore_in_Situ/hPxKAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22one%20eyed%20trouser%22&dq=%22one%20eyed%20trouser%22&printsec=frontcover) (1972)

"one-eyed trouser worm" [Take Me Home: The Rise of Country and Western Music](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Take_Me_Home/8EwUAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22one%20eyed%20trouser%20worm%22&dq=%22one%20eyed%20trouser%20worm%22&printsec=frontcover) (1974)

"winking one-eyed snake" [Canadian Drama](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Canadian_Drama/xyVaAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22one%20eyed%20snake%22%20penis&dq=%22one%20eyed%20snake%22%20penis&printsec=frontcover) (1980)

"One-eyed Dick" and "Old One-eye" [Hellenes and Hellions
Modern Greek Characters in American Literature](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hellenes_and_Hellions/bgEeAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22one%20eyed%20dick%22&dq=%22one%20eyed%20dick%22&printsec=frontcover) (1981)

"one eyed worm" [Gender The Myth of Equality](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gender/Iz2xAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22one%20eyed%20worm%22&dq=%22one%20eyed%20worm%22&printsec=frontcover) (1981)

"one-eyed monster" [Hanoi Hellground](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hanoi_Hellground/Yb6AWmLE_fAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22one%20eyed%20monster%22%20penis&dq=%22one%20eyed%20monster%22%20penis&printsec=frontcover) (1985)

Furthermore, for over 100 years, "willy" itself has meant penis.  See the [English Dialect Dictionary](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_English_Dialect_Dictionary_Being_the/ZUQOAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Willy%22%20slang%20penis&pg=RA1-PA178&printsec=frontcover) (1905).

Comment: Note that The Goonies came out in 1985. It is entirely possible that these terms came about as a direct result of the movie.

Comment: @JeanCharles I agree with you. I can't find any reference BEFORE the movie came out. Without it, I guess the whole innuendo-thing becomes unsourced.

Comment: @DanieleIavarone I added more to the answer.  The key to the phrase is the "one eyed" part.  Prior to the movie, there was a meaning of "one eyed [variable]" of "penis".

Comment: You might also want to comment on the history of using "willy" to meam penis.

Comment: @TimRias good idea, I'll add.  (Although there is already a link about this in the OP).

Comment: @DavePhD I guess the mystery is solved. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: When you live with teenagers EVERY word in your language has a sexual meaning :-)

Comment: The word "willy" has meant penis in British English for much longer than that though.